# Upload directory path - keeps reverting back to 'blogs'

Tags: uploads

EE v2.6.1

When I log in as a content manager and try to upload a file, the destination directory in File Manager reverts to 'blogs', even though the destination has been set to another directory.

If I log in as a super admin to do this, I notice that when the upload window opens initially it states momentarily that the destination is the 'blogs' directory, but then it flashes to the correct destination.

I have tried adding a new destination directory, changing permissions, and I've checked that the content user has permissions to upload to other directories.

This has just started happening, the content user was able to upload to the correct directories before, I am not entirely certain what may have changed as other users have access, but they wouldn't have changed much if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an addon is getting in the way. You can check to see if it's an Extension causing the issue by temporarily disable Extensions by adding this into your /system/expressionengine/config/config.php file:

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';
```